# Using multithreaded library within ProcessFunction with callbacks relying on the out parameter

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on a `CoProcessFunction` that uses a third party library for detecting certain patterns of events based on some rules. So, in the end, the `ProcessElement1` method is basically forwarding the events to this library and registering a callback so that, when a match is detected, the CoProcessFunction can emit an output event. For achieving this, the callback relies on a reference to the `out: Collector[T]` parameter in `ProcessElement1`.

Having said that, I am not sure whether this use case is well-supported by Flink, since:

1. There might be multiple threads spanned by the third party library (let's say I have not any control over the amount of threads spanned, this is decided by the library)
2. I am not sure whether `out` might be recreated or something by Flink at some point, invalidating the references in the callbacks, making them crash

So far I have not observed any issues, but I have just run my program in the small. It would be great to hear from the experts whether my approach is correct and how could this be approached otherwise.

---

As an update based on Arvid's comments. Since my current process function already works well for me, except for the fact I don't have access to the mailbox executor, I have simply created a custom operator for injecting that:

```
class MyOperator(myFunction: MyFunction)
  extends KeyedCoProcessOperator(myFunction)
{

  private lazy val mailboxExecutor = getContainingTask
    .getMailboxExecutorFactory
    .createExecutor(getOperatorConfig.getChainIndex)

  override def open(): Unit = {
    super.open()
    userFunction.asInstanceOf[MyFunction].mailboxExecutor = mailboxExecutor
  }
}
```

This way I can register callbacks that will send mails to be processed one by one. In the main application I use it like this:

```
.transform("wrapping function in operator", new MyOperator(new MyFunction()))
```

So far everything looks good to me, but if you see problems or know a better way, it would be great to hear your thoughts on this again. In particular, the way of getting access to the mailbox executor is definitively a bit clumsy...

Comment: We will definitively improve the way to access mailbox executor but probably also break your current way. But I don't see that coming in 1.11.

Comment: I have given extra thought to the `MailboxExecutor ` approach. I think in my case there is one caveat. Let me elaborate a bit further: In `processElement1`, I create new models using the third party lib and I register the callbacks as already discussed. These models have their own state, which evolves with the elements received in `processElement2`. When sending an element, I might get a response back in the callback. What if a checkpoint is taken after sending such an element, and a failure happens right after that, before the callback has been called? I think I would miss that one for ever.

Comment: The exactly once model of `asyncIO` is that as long as the callback has not been called or a timeout has been triggered that element will be reprocessed on recovery. As far as I have understood your question that should be good enough. Of course, from the third party perspective, it may happen that the same request is done multiple times. That's why the model needs to be stored in user state such that it in sync with the pending requests.

Comment: Thanks Arvid! What about the mailbox executor approach? There are two cases: one is when the callback does not need to be called after sending a new element to the model. That is fine. The problem is the other case, when the callback is expected to be called because the model generates some output. If a checkpoint happens after sending the element, but before the callback mail message has been sent, I will lose that invokation (which might be acceptable). Is there a way to achieve exactly one with mailbox executor instead of asyncIO?

Comment: Same thing as `asyncIO`. You should maintain a state of pending elements in your operator, which is checkpointed, and should be replayed on recovery. However, you need to figure out a way to remove those elements that do not trigger a callback (for those that trigger the callback: that's when you remove it from the state). The easiest way is still to go `asyncIO` with timeout and a larger queue size.

Comment: Makes sense, handling this myself looks like re-implementing ayncIO functionality somehow. Huge thanks Arvid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have asynchronous callbacks, you really should use `asyncIO`. So use your CoProcessFunction to emit a `Tuple2` and have a `asyncIO` directly following it.

---

Op now added that he may not get a result back at all which makes `asyncIO` difficult to use. You could rely on the timeout to trigger such that the element gets removed but that may slow down processing as asyncIO has a limited queue of "active" elements.

So, the way to go in Flink 1.10 would probably to implement a custom operator using the `MailboxExecutor`.

Getting the executor is still a bit clumsy, but you could check `AsyncWaitOperator` and the `AsyncWaitOperatorFactory`.

Code sketch for using executor

```
// setup is optionally but if you use timestamped records, you usually do that
void setup(StreamTask<?, ?> containingTask, StreamConfig config, Output<StreamRecord<OUT>> output) {
    super.setup(containingTask, config, output);

    this.timestampedCollector = new TimestampedCollector<>(output);
}

void processElement(record) {
    externalLib.addElement(record, (match) -> {
        mailboxExecutor.execute(() -> {
            timestampedCollector.collect(match);
        });
    });
}
```

Note that this involves quite a bit @PublicEvolving code and we already have some changes on our agenda. So be prepared to adjust code for 1.11.

Comment: Thanks Arvid! I was also pointed to the asyncIO pattern in the Flink User Mailing List (see [here](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Using-multithreaded-library-within-ProcessFunction-with-callbacks-relying-on-the-out-parameter-tt32701.html#none)).

Comment: Arvid, would your comment still apply if I was using AbstractStreamOperator (passing its `output` when registering the callbacks) instead of a UDF?

Comment: Yes, and it's even more important in the recent flink version 1.10.0 because we removed synchronization from different threads; everything has to be collected from the main task thread. `asyncIO` or the underlying `AsyncWaitOperator` is using that under the hood. If you really want to provide a custom operator to avoid two operators, have a look at the implementation of `AsyncWaitOperator`.

Comment: After taking a look, with Async I/O API you expect a result for each element in the input stream, so you are registering a callback together with a timeout for each expected result. This is not exactly what my use case requires. In particular, when I send an event to the third party library, I might (or not) get a result....the library is used for detecting certain patterns, so it is not as when you are querying a database, where you expect a result within a given time frame. In my case, it is more the other way around, most of the time you will not be expecting any outcome (think of alerts).

Comment: So I guess there is no callback for no matches? (If there was you could use the `asyncIO` callback and feed it an empty result set.)

Comment: You're right, there is no callback for no matches. More precisely, the callback is registered upfront only once (before sending any event) and is only called when a new result is generated by the library, but not otherwise. So, you might be sending events and getting nothing in return...until a certain thing happens (which depends on the current event sent plus the internal state held by the library itself).

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative way. If you are using an older version of Flink, your approach still might be valid (you need to acquire checkpoint lock when asynchronuously outputting elements, such that checkpointing will not see an inconsistent state).

Comment: I updated my question with a possible solution using the mailbox executor in Flink 1.10 as suggested.